# Меню как в Google Analynics

Tags: меню, css

Как можно сделать меню на подобии Google Analytics? Без картинок, только методами CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для создания элементов меню ячейки таблицы или блоки `<div>` в стиле которых укажите цвет фона. Для градиента используйте:

```
background: linear-gradient (направление, цвет1, цвет2);
```

...это на CSS3, для совместимости укажите:

```
background: Цвет1; /* Для старых браузров */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(Направление, Цвет1, Цвет2); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
/* Chrome 1-9, Safari 4-5 */
background: -webkit-gradient(Направление, Цвет1, Цвет2);
/* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(Направление, Цвет1, Цвет2);
background: -o-linear-gradient(Направление, Цвет1, Цвет2); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(Направление, Цвет1, Цвет2); /* IE10 */
```

Comment: не забываем оформить меню в <ul> и прописать ему стиль для горизонтальной ориентировки а так же убрать маркеры

Comment: кстати а что мешает запихать картинку в CSS?

Comment: хочется без картинок все сделать

Comment: без префиксное свойство нужно вставлять после свойств с префиксами

Comment: хм... в старых браузерах вероятнее всего все равно понадобится картинка, так что либо только новые либо альтернативный css со статическими картинками либо впихнуть их в тот css. насчет градиента все наверху описано